# How to use np.triu_indices to get the upper triagle value of one array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

everyone, I have some problems with one project, so I have an .tsp file to read and make one Dijkstra algorithm do solve, but my code doesn't create the matrix, can someone help me. My code is here.

```
class Matrix_Manipulation:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size
        self.elements = size**2

    def fill_matrix_upper(self, values):
        iu1 = np.triu_indices(self.elements/2, 1)
        matrix = np.zeros((self.size,self.size))
        matrix[iu1] = values
        return matrix

    def read_dist(self, tsp, tspfile):
        total = int(((tsp["DIMENSION"] + 1) ** 2) / 2)
        for n in range(1, total):
            line = tspfile.readline()
            words = deque(line.split())
            for i in words:
                if (i == "EOF"):
                    break
                else:
                    tsp["EDGE_WEIGHT_SECTION"].append(int(i))

        return tsp

    def return_list(self, tsp):
        return list(tsp["EDGE_WEIGHT_SECTION"])
```

when I scan the .tsp file works very well, but when I try to create the matrix doesn't work.

And I can't find the error, because the IDE doesn't show the error for me.

edit

---

```
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    path = open("si535.tsp", "r") 
    r = Reader() 
    tsp = r.read_tsp_file(path) 
    tsp = r.read_dist(tsp, path) 
    l = r.return_list(tsp) 
    mat = Matrix_Manipulation(int(tsp["DIMENSION"]) + 1) 
    matrix = mat.fill_matrix_upper(l) 
    print(matrix)
```

Comment: You show a class definition, but don't show any code that uses it.

Comment: `if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = open("si535.tsp", "r")
    r = Reader()
    tsp = r.read_tsp_file(path)
    tsp = r.read_dist(tsp, path)
    l = r.return_list(tsp)
    mat = Matrix_Manipulation(int(tsp["DIMENSION"]) + 1)
    matrix = mat.fill_matrix_upper(l)
    print(matrix)`

Comment: the unique usage of the code